# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value on NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift

here's my code:

```
1.  let combinedFormatter = dateFormatter
2.  var mFormatter: NSDateFormatter!
3.  var hFormatter: NSDateFormatter!
4.  mFormatter.dateFormat = "mm"
5.  hFormatter.dateFormat = "hh"        
6.  let timeString: NSString = timeLabel.text
7.  let selectedString: NSString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(selectedDate)
8.  var a1: Int = timeString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 2)).toInt()!
9.  var a2: Int = selectedString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 2)).toInt()!
10. var b1: Int = timeString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(3, 2)).toInt()!
11. var b2: Int = selectedString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(3, 2)).toInt()!
```

I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I've go this error on 4th, 5th, 8th, 9th, 10th, 11th lines. I am beginning to move from Objective-C to Swift, so I need some help.

Comment: @Zaph: You are absolutely incorrect. Firstly, it's called **implicit unwrapping**. And your comment is nonsensical, as both optional types are *used* to represent `nil`.

Comment: Line 8-11 are implicit unwrapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatter variables are `nil`, and instances of `NSDateFormatter` must be created before being used. Change these lines:

```
2.  var mFormatter: NSDateFormatter!
3.  var hFormatter: NSDateFormatter!
```

to:

```
2.  var mFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
3.  var mFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
```

`<type>!` is syntactic sugar for `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<type>`. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).